# Strange substitute() behavior inside lapply()

Tags: r

Could someone explain the following result :

```
R> lapply(1:2, function(v) substitute(v))
[[1]]
1:2[[2L]]

[[2]]
1:2[[2L]]
```

Given the definition of `lapply`, I thought that this should have returned a list with elements `substitute(1)` and `substitute(2)`. It is as if `substitute(v)` was not evaluated in the anonymous function scope, but in the "parent" one.

What I find even more strange is that if I add `eval` to `substitute`, I get the result I was waiting for :

```
R> lapply(1:2, function(v) eval(substitute(v)))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

I know these questions are a bit tricky, but there is clearly something I don't get here.

Comment: This is related to lazy evaluation. "Substitution takes place by examining each component of the parse tree as follows: [...] If it is a promise object, i.e., a formal argument to a function [...], the expression slot of the promise replaces the symbol." I think this is part of the explanation, although it's hard to parse for me. Also, `lapply(1:2, function(v) print(substitute(v)))` is interesting, too.

Comment: I think some of  the confusion is that what's returned is a `call` , not the integers themselves.  Try `lapply(c("me","you"),function(v)substitute(v)` , which also returns a `call` of course, but is easier (at least for me :-) ) to distinguish.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck   Sub-question:  `bar<-lapply(1:2, function(v) substitute(v)) ; class(bar[[1]]) #call; class(bar[[1]][3] #call ` , but while `eval(bar[[1]])` returns `2` , `eval(bar[[1]][3]` returns an error. What is the reason one thing of class `call` works but not the other?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Ah, I didn't understand that [[2L]] was the representation of indexing operation. But you're right, as I understand it the first element of `lapply(1:2, function(v) substitute(v))` should be `1:2[[1L]]` ?

Comment: As inidicated by Roland this is related to promises and also the fact that `substitute` does not follow the usual R rules so its not really exlainable by the usual rules.  Slightly easier to understand is `funs <- lapply(c("A", "B"), function(v) function() v); funs[[1]]()` which returns `"B"`, not `"A"`, due to lazy evaluation.